# Multiple HTML div elements in single javascript object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to use mulitple HTML div elements inside one JS object property (content in the example below):

```
$.Box({
                title : "Title",
                content : "<table id='1'></table>",
                "<table id='2'></table>"

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to store them in an **array** .

**Example 1 :**

```
$.Box({
     title : "Title",
     content : ["<table id='1'></table>","<table id='2'></table>"]
  });
```

**Example 2 :**

```
 $.Box({
     title : "Title",
     content : function(){
        var format = ["<table id='1'></table>","<table id='2'></table>"];
        //do something to the format
       return format.join(" ");
      }()
  });
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

That isn't valid javascript for an object

Put all the html inside same quotes so it is all one string

```
$.Box({
       title : "Title",
       content : "<table id='1'></table><table id='2'></table>"
});
```

Or use a `+` to concatenate the string parts

```
$.Box({
       title : "Title",
       content : "<table id='1'></table>" + 
                 "<table id='2'></table>"
});
```

Comment: You can also use an array